# Using another logger in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, logging

In one specific situation, I want to use an alternative log file for sidekiq background jobs. So I instantiate a new Logger, but the problem is it doesn't allow me to use debug:

```
 include Sidekiq::Worker

  def sidekiq_logger
     @@sidekiq_logger ||= Logger.new("#{Rails.root}/log/sidekiq.log")
   end

  def perform(report_id)
    report = Report.find(report_id)

    distance = report.distance_formatted(report.unit)
    sidekiq_logger.debug = "#{DateTime.now.to_s(:db)}: #{distance} processed for report #{report.id}"

    report.update_attribute(:processed, true)
  end
```

exception raised:

```
2013-07-16T13:17:35Z 10803 TID-tfkn8 ReportsWorker JID-e8f0f8a52277238c4851f231 INFO: fail: 0.007 sec
2013-07-16T13:17:35Z 10803 TID-tfkn8 WARN: {"retry"=>true, "queue"=>"default", "class"=>"ReportsWorker", "args"=>[317$
2013-07-16T13:17:35Z 10803 TID-tfkn8 WARN: undefined method `debug=' for #<Logger:0x00000006174d40>
```

How do I use debug then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a guess, but shouldn't it be 'debug' without the '='?